# SSL not working on symlinked files

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ssl, symlink

I have a virtual (CentOS) webserver running Apache. I have multiple websites running. Two websites share the same set of core files and have a common database. The files are "shared" via symlinks. Site1's files are the real files and site2's "files" are the symlinks of site1.

When browsing site2 in a non-SSL encrypted browser, the site works as intended. But as I try to view the site using the https protocol, the site appears to be empty. The SSL certificate was installed by the hosting company.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You may not have `FollowSymLinks` in the `Options` of the SSL vhost. The ssl vhost is distinct from the non-SSL vhost and has separate configuration. Both will inherit config from the default vhost config.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because the SSL certificate was certified for site1, but not for site2.  This would explain why it would work for http but not for https.  What are the two domain names?

Comment: No, it was created for site2, and has been installed in site2.